# how to associate nested child table values with parent table row and inserts child tables values corresponds to that parent table row in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 nested tables. Parent table row contains child table. Both tables can add rows if needed by add button. parent table values insert in a product_size table in database and child table values inserts in a product_color table. Parent table contains sizes and child table contains color and quantity of items of that size. I want to insert child table values(color & quantity) across parent table row. Means parent first row child table values should insert across parent first row only and the child table values that is in the second row of parent table should insert across parent second row. Currently, my code takes all Child table values from all rows of the parent table and inserts in the database across the first row and then takes all Child table values from all rows of parent table again and inserts in the database across the second row of the parent table. Please Check my code and help me point out where is the problem in my code. /PHP CODE/

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysqli_select_db($con,"login"); 

    for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['size']); $i++){

        $size = $_POST['size'][$i];          

        $qry1="INSERT INTO product_size (product_size) VALUES ('$size')";

        $result1=mysqli_query($con,$qry1);
        $product_size_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);                    

        for ($j=0; $j<count($_POST['color']); $j++){

            $quantity = $_POST['dress_quantity'][$j];

            $color = $_POST['color'][$j];

            $qry2="INSERT INTO product_color (product_size_id, product_color, product_quantity) VALUES ('$product_size_id', '$color', '$quantity')";

            $result2=mysqli_query($con,$qry2); 
            if($result2)
            {
                echo '<script>alert("Record Added Successfully!")</script>';
                echo '<script>window.location="try.php"</script>';
            }
            else      
            {
                die("Error While Adding Stock! Please Try Again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

/*HTML and Javascript*/

```js
function addRow(tableID) {

      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;
      var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
      var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

      for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        if (i == colCount - 1) //last column which adds child table
        {
        //Get child table id of first row
        var tableID = table.rows[1].cells[i].childNodes[1].getAttribute("id"); 

        //Replace all occurances of parent table id's with new unique table id for child table before writing the information to DOM
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(tableID,"g"), "dataTable" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1));
        }

        else  //For other columns there is no need to assign unique id for controls
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;

        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
          case "text":
              newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
              break;
          case "checkbox":
              newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
              break;
          case "select-one":
              newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
              break;
        }
      }
    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
      try {
      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;

      for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
          if(rowCount <= 1) {
            alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
            break;
          }
          table.deleteRow(i);
          rowCount--;
          i--;
        }  
      }
      }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
      }
    }

  
    function addRow1(tableID) {

      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

      var rowCount = table.rows.length;
      var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

      var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

      for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
          case "text":
              newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
              break;
          case "checkbox":
              newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
              break;
          case "select-one":
              newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
              break;
        }
      }
    }

    function deleteRow1(tableID) {
      try {
      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;

      for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
          if(rowCount <= 1) {
            alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
            break;
          }
          table.deleteRow(i);
          rowCount--;
          i--;
        }


      }
      }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
      }
    }
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid #1E90FF;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    border:1px solid #1E90FF;

}



th {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<TABLE id="dataTable">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                  <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;Select&nbsp;</th>    
                  <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<b>Size</b>&nbsp;</th>
                  <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<b>Color & Quantity</b>&nbsp;</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  
                  <tbody>
                  <tr id='C1' class='customer'>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
                  <td><select  name="size[]" id="size" required="" >
                  <option value="">Select Size</option>
                  <option value="Small">Small</option>
                  <option value=">Medium">Medium</option>
                  <option value="Large">Large</option>
                  </select></td>
                  <td>

                  <TABLE style="margin-top: 20px;" id="dataTable1" width="400px" border="1">
                  <thead>
                  <th>&nbsp;Select&nbsp;</th>    
                  <th>&nbsp;<b>Color&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Quantity</b>&nbsp;</th>  
                  </thead> 
                  <TR>
                  <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
                  <TD>
                  <select name="color[]" required="" >
                    <option value="">Select Color</option>
                    <option value="Red">Red</option>   
                    <option value="Green">Green</option>   
                    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>    
                    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
                  </select>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <input style="width: 120px; height: 26px; " oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" name="dress_quantity[]" class="qty1"  min="1" max="1000" maxlength="4" placeholder="Size Quantity" value="" required="">  
                  </TD>
                  </TR>
                  </TABLE>
                  
                  <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow1('dataTable1')" />
                  <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow1('dataTable1')" />
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  </TABLE>
                  <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
                  <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
```

Comment: I think your trouble may lie in that when you submit your form, all your child are called the same name (i.e. color or dress_quantity) then you loop through ALL sizes and ALL colors and dress quantity like you said. Instead if you rename each parent row size1[], size2[] ...sizeN[], and then your child color arrays, color1[] for parent row size1[] and then color2[] for size2[], you could iterate through your form and insert only colors from color2[] for size2[]

Comment: @ bio_sprite how i can replace name like size1[],size2[] as my data is not static?

Comment: can you please help?

Comment: I see you copy the inner html from the first parent row's children (function addRow1, newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;) If instead you create the color dropdown element and quantity input elements each time, you can simply change the name attribute by using setAttribute element.setAttribute("name", "someName3");

Comment: oops, I meant addRow (not addRow1). I see you use a replace to give the table a new id. Perhaps you could use similar way to search and replace size[] with size1[]

Comment: sizes are added dynamically by user it depends upon how many rows added so i can't change names because i don't know exactly how many rows user will add

Comment: true, you would have to keep a counter somewhere for each time the user adds or deletes a parent row to know how many parent rows the user has added. It could be that each time there is a new parent row, the javascript gets and updates a hidden input value which stores this value.

Comment: can you please give me a demo? i will be thankful to you

Comment: I am stucked in this problem from last 3 weeks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is just an example with changes just for child table for color:

Note- I tested the javascript and html in jsbin but did not confirm/test the php

Hope this helps!

//html

```
<TABLE id="dataTable">
                 <thead>
                  <tr>
                  <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;Select&nbsp;</th>    
                  <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<b>Size</b>&nbsp;</th>
                  <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<b>Color & Quantity</b>&nbsp;</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <tbody>
                  <tr id='C1' class='customer'>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
                  <td><select  name="size[]" id="size" required="" >
                  <option value="">Select Size</option>
                  <option value="Small">Small</option>
                  <option value=">Medium">Medium</option>
                  <option value="Large">Large</option>
                  </select></td>
                  <td>

                  <TABLE style="margin-top: 20px;" id="dataTable1" width="400px" border="1">
                  <thead>
                  <th>&nbsp;Select&nbsp;</th>    
                  <th>&nbsp;<b>Color&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Quantity</b>&nbsp;</th>  
                  </thead> 
                  <TR>
                  <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
                  <TD>
                  <select name="color1[]" required="" >
                    <option value="">Select Color</option>
                    <option value="Red">Red</option>   
                    <option value="Green">Green</option>   
                    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>    
                    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
                  </select>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <input style="width: 120px; height: 26px; " oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" name="dress_quantity[]" class="qty1"  min="1" max="1000" maxlength="4" placeholder="Size Quantity" value="" required="">  
                  </TD>
                  </TR>
                  </TABLE>


                  <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow1('dataTable1')" />
                  <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow1('dataTable1')" />
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  </TABLE>


                  <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

                  <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

                  <!--this could be hidden-->
                  <INPUT type="text" id="myCounter" name="myCounter" value="1">
```

//javascript

```
   function addRow(tableID) {

      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
      var myCounter = document.getElementById('myCounter');
      var myCounterValue = myCounter.value;
      myCounterValue++; //increment value
      myCounter.value = myCounterValue; //set incremented value into myCounter input

      var rowCount = table.rows.length;
      var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
      var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

      for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        if (i == colCount - 1) //last column which adds child table
        {
        //Get child table id of first row
        var tableID = table.rows[1].cells[i].childNodes[1].getAttribute("id"); 
        //alert(tableID);

        //Replace all occurances of parent table id's with new unique table id for child table before writing the information to DOM
        var newTableID = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(tableID,"g"), "dataTable" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1));

        //Replace all occurances of child table name with new name for child table before writing the information to DOM
        var originalColorName = 'color1'; //you remove the brackets
        newTableID =  newTableID.replace(/[[\]]/g,''); //remove square brackets from name
        var newColorName = newTableID.replace(new RegExp(originalColorName,"m"), "color" + myCounterValue + "[]");


        newcell.innerHTML = newColorName;

        }

        else  //For other columns there is no need to assign unique id for controls
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;

        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
          case "text":
              newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
              break;
          case "checkbox":
              newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
              break;
          case "select-one":
              newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
              break;
        }
      }
    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
      try {
      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;

      for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
          if(rowCount <= 1) {
            alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
            break;
          }
          table.deleteRow(i);
          rowCount--;
          i--;
        }  
      }
      }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
      }
    }


    function addRow1(tableID) {

      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

      var rowCount = table.rows.length;
      var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

      var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

      for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
          case "text":
              newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
              break;
          case "checkbox":
              newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
              break;
          case "select-one":
              newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
              break;
        }
      }
    }

    function deleteRow1(tableID) {
      try {
      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;

      for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
          if(rowCount <= 1) {
            alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
            break;
          }
          table.deleteRow(i);
          rowCount--;
          i--;
        }


      }
      }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
      }
    }
```

//php

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {   
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysqli_select_db($con,"login"); 

    $number_of_parent_rows = $_POST['myCounter'];
    for (var $r=1; $r <= $number_of_parent_rows; $r++){
         //do a check here to see if your index exists as you do not decrement your counter
       if( !isset($_POST['color'.$r])){
              continue; //if index is not set, exit out of loop and go to next
        }

        for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['size']); $i++){

        $size = $_POST['size'][$i];          

        $qry1="INSERT INTO product_size (product_size) VALUES ('$size')";

        $result1=mysqli_query($con,$qry1);
        $product_size_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);                    

        for ($j=0; $j<count($_POST['color'.$r]); $j++){

            $quantity = $_POST['dress_quantity'][$j];

            $color = $_POST['color'.$r][$j];

            $qry2="INSERT INTO product_color (product_size_id, product_color, product_quantity) VALUES ('$product_size_id', '$color', '$quantity')";

            $result2=mysqli_query($con,$qry2); 
            if($result2)
            {
                echo '<script>alert("Record Added Successfully!")</script>';
                echo '<script>window.location="try.php"</script>';
            }
            else      
            {
                die("Error While Adding Stock! Please Try Again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never done this before, but I think you can view here https://jsbin.com/zewikaqice/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Oops that is supposed to be $r...but please check the counter. I forgot that the original color doesn't have a number so isn't included. I think you should be able to fix by changing initial color[] to color1[] and then making sure to change the regrex

Comment: Also a note that my regrex replace assumes there are no other instances of 'color' that you wouldn't want to be replaced